# postgresql insert from select query, plus static values

Tags: postgresql, insert

Referring to [How to insert values into a table from a select query in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql),

I would like to INSERT into a table rows from another, specified by a SELECT DISTINCT, plus some **static values**, something like:

```
INSERT INTO new_tbl (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM -- long where clause --, 
  'a string', 0;
```

So that every row in the new table will get the same values for column2 and column3 Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can put static values into SELECT clause.

```
INSERT INTO new_tbl (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT DISTINCT id, 'a string', 0 FROM -- long where clause --;
```

Comment: *facepalm*...  how on earth was I not seeing this? select query too long ;)

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)