# Postgres handle case to continue Insert other row if some row doesn't exists

Tags: postgresql, query, insert

I am trying to insert data to a table using below query:

```
INSERT INTO projects_users (user_id, project_id, is_admin) VALUES (
            (Select id from users where username='example'),
            (Select id from projects where name='example'),
            True
        ),(
            (Select id from users where username='example'),
            (Select id from projects where name='example'),
            True
        )
```

This query fails when some user is not there in users table (`Select id from users where username='does_not_exists'`).

I want to handle such cases, and skip such rows (where username doesn't exists) and continue adding other rows.

In case of duplicate rows, I know we can do "On Conflict Do Nothing". Is there something similar available for cases like this? And is it a good practice to do?

Comment: Remove the `values` clause and turn it into a `select` that returns 0 or 1 row depending on what data exists.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Build a `SELECT` expression that does what you want, and then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to insert it into the table.

To get a `SELECT` that does what you want, wrap the `VALUES` expression in parentheses, add an alias with field names for your sub-selects, then add a `WHERE` for the project and user IDs being `NOT NULL`. The [final query becomes](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bbu6VGa2wxoRqwoJp6Dcxy/0):

```
insert into projects_users select * from 
(VALUES (
            (Select id from users where username='user_id1'),
            (Select id from projects where name='project_id2'),
            True
        ),(
            (Select id from users where username='user_id3'),
            (Select id from projects where name='project_id4'),
            True
        )
) as r(user_id, project_id, is_admin)
WHERE user_id is not null and project_id is not null;
```